How to add new property to definePageMeta
How do I add a new property in definePageMeta and access it in the application, whether in middleware or via useRoute()
On any page, for example:
definePageMeta({
  myProperty : "value string or array or any"
});

For example, middleware :
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to) => {
  if(to.meta.myProperty === "any") {
    //code
  }
});

or in any Page :
const route = useRoute();

if(route.meta.myProperty) {
  // code
}


I want it to be available when writing, for example, to.meta.| show in list and click enter to add.

Guess using Typescript to wrap the existing types with your own is the way to go.

How do I update definePageMeta, meaning I add new propertys in ts at the application level? Thank you

Seems like you can't do that.
Here are the options available: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/define-page-meta#type
If you need some data available across pages, consider using state.
